# Client persistence issue with SharedObjectBean (Swiz framework)

Tags: apache-flex, swiz

I am using Swiz framework in my flex application. I am using SharedObjectBean for client persistence. It is working fine, but the problem is when I close the browser and again restart the application then client persistence does not work. There is an file with .sol extension is getting created in AppData folder when I save the session. But when I close the browser then that file gets deleted.

Can someone help me out with the way to have client persistence on restarting the application after the closing the browser?